# how does pointers work in type define in c?

Tags: c

I am new to C programming, I am trying to understand the following code:

```
typedef eMBErrorCode( *peMBFrameSend ) ( UCHAR slaveAddress,
                                         const UCHAR * pucFrame,
                                         USHORT usLength );
```

Could any one explain how does this code works?

Comment: This code declares `peMBFrameSend` to be a type alias for "pointer to a function returning `eMBErrorCode` and taking arguments `UCHAR slaveAddress, const UCHAR * pucFrame, USHORT usLength`".

Comment: It's a function pointer, see the linked duplicate.

Comment: [int( *peMBFrameSend ) (char,   const char *,  short)](https://cdecl.org/?q=int%28+*peMBFrameSend+%29+%28char%2C+++const+char+*%2C++short%29%3B+) may help